# MacBook Pro Input/Output audio not found

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, audio, siri

I have an audio problem on my MackBook with the following specifications:

- MB Pro Retina (13 inch Early 2015)
- Operation System: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Here is the chronology of the problem: Initially, everything was okay. I could hear music from iTunes on my MBP connected with a cable to an external speaker. Then I accidentally unplugged the cable on the speaker, so I plugged it in again but then I couldn't hear sound from my MacBook anymore.

I have tried the following solutions to address this:

1. Restarting my MacBook
2. Reinstalling my operating system
3. Resetting both NVRAM and SMC
4. Plugging and unplugging to/from the audio jack on the MBP
5. Killing coreaudiod on Activity Monitor
6. Deleting the apple.bezleservices.plist file at `~Library/Preferences/com.apple.BezelServices.plist`
7. Taking it into Apple Store Service near my town

The Apple Store said it was a hardware issue, but I'm not sure on this. So, I went home to try the various "non-hardware" approaches above.

**FYI:** My iTunes and Siri also don't work. Playing a song in iTunes shows no song progress. If I try to use Siri I get a "no audio found" message.

Below are various screenshots of my problem:

[image]

**My questions:**

- How can I troubleshoot this further?
- Is there a way for me to narrow down whether or not this is definitely a hardware issue?

Comment: same issue with Macbook Air

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced a similar problem.  I discovered that when I plugged in my external speakers (in the radio plug port), my System Preferences defaulted to a lower volume output setting (presumably to prevent blasting out too much volume in small speakers).  Try opening System Preferences and resetting the output volume to a higher setting.

Comment: In the system preferences the output volume is disable with the mute option is checked as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Of course the output volume is disabled when the MUTE button is checked. That's why it's called MUTE. Unclick the MUTE button.

Comment: I can't click it since it is disable as well